# How to analyze the equation $(x-y)^2=2\big( (x+y)-2\sqrt{xy} \big)$?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

Suppose that $x,y$ are positive real numbers and that

$$ (x-y)^2=2\big( (x+y)-2\sqrt{xy} \big). \tag{*}$$

**Then Mathematica claims that one of the following $3$ options holds:**

$$1. \, \, \,  x=y.$$
$$2. \, \, \, x = y - 2 \sqrt 2 \sqrt y + 2.$$
$$3. \, \, \, x = y + 2 \sqrt 2 \sqrt y + 2.$$

(Option $3$ is in fact impossible over the reals.)

Also, if I interpret the results correctly, the last two options $(2,3)$ are only possible when $xy \le \frac{1}{4}$. When $xy \ge \frac{1}{4}$ only option $(1)$ is possible.

> Is there a way to prove this analytically (without using a computer)?

**Edit:**

We assume $x \ge 0,y \ge 0$.
In the [answer below](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3641610/104576), we rewrite equation $(*)$ as
$(x - y)^2 = 2 ( \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2$, which gives

$$ (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})=x - y =\pm \sqrt{2} ( \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}).$$

Thus, either $x=y$ or $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}=\pm \sqrt{2}$. 
If $x,y$ are non-negative reals, then $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}=- \sqrt{2}$ is ruled out.

So, we are left with 
$$\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}= \sqrt{2} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x} =  \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{y} \Rightarrow x=y - 2 \sqrt 2 \sqrt y + 2.$$

The third option actually comes from the branch where  $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}=- \sqrt{2}$, and then $x,y$ are complex numbers.

Next, we show that $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}= \sqrt{2}$ is possible  if and only if $xy \le \frac{1}{4}$.

By the AM-GM inequality $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}}{2}\ge  \sqrt{\sqrt{xy}}$.

On the other hand, suppose that $\sqrt{xy} =s \le \frac{1}{2}$. Writing $a=\sqrt x,b=\sqrt y$, we are looking for $a,b \ge 0$ such that $ab=s,a+b=\sqrt{2}$. This is a quadratic equation, and since the AM-GM holds it has real solutions, which must be positive.

(Indeed, since $s=ab$ is positive, then $a,b$ have the same sign, and $a+b=\sqrt{2}>0$ implies they are both positive.

The quadratic is
$$ t^2-\sqrt 2 t+s=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factorise to $(x - y)^2 = 2 ( \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})^2$. Which in turn gives $(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}) = \pm \sqrt{2} (\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y})$. So $x=y$ or $\sqrt{x} = \pm \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: To take the parabola part: $(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^2=2$ or part of $4xy=(2-x-y)^2$ which is the parabola of focus $(1,1)$ and directrix $x+y=0,$ since the equation can be written $2((x+y)^2/2-(x-1)^2-(y-1)^2)=0.$

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you are trying to say exactly in this comment. Can you please elaborate? Thanks.